# Question about changing IDs with user control and master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

In my user control I got this inline CSS in which I have only css classes...
like I am not setting any attribute or whatever on some ID..got only classes like :-

```
.sp
{
backgrond-image :url(blah blah);
}
```

and so on..

nothing of the sort

```
#id1
{
/* set some property here*/
}
```

Now my question:-

Do I need to worry about system generated IDs if the CSS in my user control got only classes ? like in my page source..the divs ID changes from their original ID to something like `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_ctl00_Banner_divBanner` after adding usercontrol and master page ...

so changing IDs shouldn't make any difference..right ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webforms, prior to .NET 4.0 all had auto-generated ID's. It was never a good idea to reference an ID as a CSS selector. With .NET 4.0 you have the ability to not auto-generate the ID's and use your normal "nice" ID's.

I would recommend sticking with class selectors, as most controls offer `classname` as a property.

[Good article on the new .NET client ID's.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)

Comment: so what I have done won't make no difference in whatever way..right ? haven't used ID selectors in my css

Comment: Yes, the class selector would not change.